Monitor suddenly not able to show full resolution
I have a M1 Macbook Pro running Sonoma 14.6.1 with an LG external monitor.
I've had no problem using this Mac and monitor for the last few years, connecting them with HDMI, until now.
Now I cannot make the monitor full resolution - I only have 2 choices in System Preferences: 1280 x 720 and 1920 x 1080. The recommended resultion for the monitor is 3840 x 2160.
I've restarted the Mac and messed around with the monitor settings to no avail.
Would anyone know what I can do?

I can't speak to the then vs now, but does the behavior change if you interface via DisplayPort?
